# No raw data (Omniauth-vkontakte)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have an error "No raw data" when I'm trying to log in via Vkontakte using Omniauth-Vkontakte gem. I could see throught console that I recieve code and state from VK, but after that I have an error. I'm using Omniauth-Vkontakte 1.4.1, Omniauth 1.6.1. Besides, I'm using logging in via facebook google, yandex, github and all except Vkontakte works fine. Are there any possible solutions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a depricated API version in my gem. Sorry for so stupid question